# How to check passed int parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This was more complicated than I thought! It's easy to check if a string is empty or null, but how is this done with an int? Perhaps equal easy, but I'm stuck!

I pass an int from a html form input field to an action method in the controller, but despite all combinations I try, nothing works! It seems that `!` is not possible to use with an int. First of all, could an int be null?

What I want to check if a user has clicked the submit button without entered a number. I also want to check if it's an int and not a string? Some help is appreciated!

Comment: An `int` cannot be `null`, no. If this is a textbox where the user enters a number and clicks submit, you should accept the input as text and do both client-side pattern validation and server-side pattern and conversion validation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for your comment! If I understand you correct, you mean that the action method should have a string parameter instead of int and then check the input if it's null or empty and finally make some conversion from string to int!?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: OK, I will try that!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`int` cannot be a null (it is always a number), for an example you can output an `int` thats not set, like this

```
Console.WriteLine(default(int));
```

What you can do is to make a nullable `int` aka. `int?` (the `?` makes a property nullable)

Whats usually done is to have a value that is never used, like if you are working on an array then -1 is a nice value to use as the "skip-value" then you just test for that special value.

On a controller then just don't pass the value if its not set and just default construct it to null on a `int?`.

```
public string Method(string value, int? number = null)
{
    if(number.HasValue)
    {
        //DoWork with int
    }
    else
    {
        //Do work without int
    }
    return "result";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Int has a default value if not assigned anything. To achieve what you're trying to, use the nullable integer type. `int?` is just like `int`, but it can have a null value, so if you don't receive anything, a simple `== null` will do the trick.